# Wordpress: PHP code rendering in the wrong place

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I'm trying to insert a php code for a post-rating on wordpress. It used to work out of the echo normally and in-place. Now, using this code, instead of the rating showing up after "User Rating:" it renders completely out of the 'anime-info' div and show up above it.

The code is " . `the_ratings()` . " The full code should be: but " . `if(function_exists('the_ratings')) { the_ratings() }` . " didn't work so I had to change it.

Here's the full code. Basically, if the category ID assigned to the current post is 4, it shows this text and an image. If it's not, it renders only a image.

Any suggestions?

This is the plugin I'm using http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-postratings/.

Thanks!

```
<?php foreach((get_the_category()) as $category)
        { if($category->cat_ID = 4){ echo "<div class='anime-info'>
                <div class='anime-inf left'>
                <b>Anime Title:</b> ".get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'anime_title', true )."<br />
                <b>Creator:</b> ".get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'anime_creator', true )."<br />
                <b>Genres:</b> ".the_tags()." <br />
                <b>Studio:</b> ".get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'anime_studio', true )."<br />
                <b>First aired at:</b> ".get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'anime_firstaired', true )."<br />
                <b># of Episodes:</b> ".get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'anime_episodes', true )."<br />
                <b>Official Website:</b> ".get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'anime_website', true )."<br />
                <b>Anime ii Rating:</b> ".get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'anime_revrating', true )."<br /> <br />
                <b>User Rating:</b>" .  the_ratings() . "
                </div>
                <div class='post-image-inner right'>
                   img src='".get_bloginfo( 'template_directory' )."/timthumb.php?src=".get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'image_value', true )."&amp;w=225&amp;h=246&amp;zc=1' />
                    </div>
                    </div>"; 
            }else{ echo "<div class='post-image'><img src='".get_bloginfo('template_directory')."/timthumb.php?src=".get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'image_value', true )."&amp;w=529&amp;h=253&amp;zc=1' /></div>";
                                }
                            }
                    ?>
```

Comment: It sounds like a CSS problem - not a PHP problem.

Comment: I guess it is..
I edited with the rendered rating code from the source code.

Comment: If you have an answer, please post the answer and then mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is as simple as that:

```
ob_start(); 
eval("?>".the_ratings()."<?php "); 
$ratings=ob_get_contents(); 
ob_end_clean();
```

Then you call it:

OR ".$ratings."

Depends on the situation. :)